# array filter using the iterating variable in a regex test function

Tags: javascript

This javascript tries to return the element of the input array which is found in a string 'case insensitive'

```
'4WD 4X4 2WD 4X2'.split(' ').filter((y) => {
  return /y/gi.test('2007 Toyota 4wd Land cruiser')
})
```

And expected to get `'4WD'`

I tried `/'+y+'/gi` for no avail. Any ideas how to do it? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object and test with it.

```js
var result = '4WD 4X4 2WD 4X2'
        .split(' ')
        .filter(y => new RegExp(y, 'gi').test('2007 Toyota 4wd Land cruiser'));

console.log(result);
```